# How do I copy photos edited via the Camera app on my iPhone to my PC?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, photos, camera

So, I know that the photos edited via the Camera app can't be copied to a Windows PC along with the edits.

I realise that the alternative is to email 5 photos at a time.

This is obviously cumbersome. Can anyone suggest alternatives?

Comment: You should be able to save the photos with the changes made. So the picture should be saved as new file. Then you can import it including changes I think

Comment: That's the problem. If I had a Mac and iPhoto, I could do that. But since I have a PC, the vanilla photo is what can be copied.

Comment: No I think it should be able to save the pictures including changes on your iPhone. I used this possibility only once and it was on iOS 5 or something... but I think the function should still be there

Comment: It isn't possible. You can't "get" the edits onto your Desktop/Laptop if you're using a Windows PC by simply connecting your iPhone via cable to the computer and then copying.

Comment: when I save a edited picture, there is a second picture in my folder on iPhone... isn't it visible over PC?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I've found it.

The easiest alternative to getting the edits onto your PC, instead of emailing them to yourselves is to upload it to Flickr.

Obviously, you'll need iOS7, as it has native Flickr integration.

You can upload 10 photos at once which is far better than emailing.

Moreover, if you're like me, who backups photos to a cloud, you can use [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) to create a trigger and upload it to your favorite service whenever a new photo is uploaded.

Comment: I tell you, I don't know how people put up with apple. I am reading people complain about this since 2011 and apple in 4 years has not come up with a solution.
Users that are in a place where they don't have internet are left with ZERO choices. And users with a USB 3 port available are left with the option of using iCloud upload that is at least 1000 times slower and spends bandwidth for nothing. Just because some smart guy at apple design decided "hey, you know what would be cool? To screw with users and just show the original photo when they edit them". And people pay 600+ euros for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use iCloud.  On your phone go to Settings > iCloud and enable Photos.  It may take some time to sync, but they will.

Then go to iCloud.com and log into your account from your PC.  Then you can browse your iCloud files including your photos that you've sync'd from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of wireless syncing options.

If you want to upload a small number of photos I would suggest using Google Drive / Dropbox; both support multiupload, you only select the ones you want to upload and they will just appear in according folders on your PC.

If you want to upload your entire photo stream you can start using Google Photos. It can be configured to upload only when on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I had hundreds of photos **edited** on iOS that I needed to transfer (yes, I actually did edit that many photos in my case)

Here's a solution I recently used, https://send-anywhere.com/ (free at the time of this writing)

Both the sender and receiver can receive/send files via the website, Android App or iOS App.

So, it's not just for PCs, but any platform. And obviously, it's not just for photos, but for files in general.

---

Additional notes:

In my case, I was trying to transfer **edited** photos from my iPhone to my Mac, and I initially used **Photos** to import them, which transferred the **original** ones (i.e. not what I wanted).

Then I used AirDrop, which did transfer the **edited** ones, but are all named as FullSizeRender.jpg, FullSizeRender(1).jpg, FullSizeRender(2).jpg, etc, but **not in the order I selected**. It almost seemed like whichever file gets fully received first gets the available name first (again, not what I wanted)

So I ended up selecting my photos on iPhone, sharing to the Send Anywhere app, and downloaded the files from my Mac. I got the same file name patterns, but this time they were all in the sequence I expected and wanted, which I can live with.

Those were photos of dozens of pages of notes I had, so I specifically didn't want them to be transferred and named in random order.

---

Unconfirmed speculations:

From the AirDrop experience I mentioned, if you actually have *two* Apple devices, I'm speculating that the **edited** photos get transferred from one device to another.

If this is true, then you can first send the edited photos from one device to the second, then through USB/wire, transfer your edited photos from the second device to your PC.

I can't actually try this yet - if someone can confirm this, that would be great.

Answer (score -4):

You can find the solution on this link:

[How to import to Mac/Windows the iOS edited images without losing the changes](https://isalinis.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/how-to-import-to-macwindows-the-ios-edited-images-without-losing-the-changes/)

;-)

Comment: While the linked post may answer the question, we actually prefer to have the answer directly on site, with a link to the post for reference. This way the answer remains valid/useful even if the link changes or the web site it points to goes offline.